# Port MessagEase Macro to new device

Tags: keyboard, device-migration, messagease-keyboard

I have a new phone and a lot of [MessagEase](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.exideas.mekb&hl=en) on my old phone. Unfortunately, they haven't been transferred with the default process to migrate to a new device. 
Is there another way to port them over apart from copy pasting every single one?

Comment: You might wish to take a look at our [adb tag-wiki](/tags/adb/info). If the app doesn't block backups, you could simply `adb backup` it from the old device, and restore it to the new using `adb restore`. Piece of cake if you've got ADB running – but if you did not yet, the tricky part is setting it up (if you're on Windows that is; it's not that difficult on Linux).

Answer (score 0):

Note: I wanted to post this as a comment, but have yet to reach the requisite reputation requirement; I'd appreciate if someone can move this for me, or if not just ignore me, thank you!

I double checked and MessagEase does indeed have the backup flag enabled in its manifest, so as @Izzy pointed out ADB backup should be a viable method to export them all (personally, I am still having issues with the ADB restore function, just be aware it may not throw any error messages from syntaxical issues by default, and do some further reading on how to troubleshoot).  If you do wind up having to do it manually, note that holding down the hand icon key with a keyboard's hex data on-screen supposedly brings you to the keyboard exchange step and imports it (according to the app's FAQ, I have not tried the feature myself); that might help cut down the labor/time a bit.

**Additional Thoughts**
I initially thought maybe one might be able to find where all the hex values for keyboards are being stored in some directory in root, but apparently it's a bit more complicated for IME/input devices than I'd assumed.  Someone else more knowledgeable might be able to advise on locating such a directory (or potentially in a .db?).